# How to get all occurences/text elements of a certain class from a beautifulsoup object

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I would like to fetch the URL = 'https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/new-cryptocurrency-listing?c=48&navId=48' and save all text elements in a python set.

All the list items from this URL seem to have in common the class 'css-f94ykk'. However, the code that goes through my beautifulsoup object can't catch them.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/new-cryptocurrency-listing?c=48&navId=48'

response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

title_set = set()

for text_element in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "css-f94ykk"}):  # class_="css-f94ykk"
    title_set.add(text_element.get_text())

print(title_set)

# print(soup.prettify())
```

Why does my set not get filled with the text elements?
Thanks very much in advance!

Tried it also with `soup.find_all(class_="css-f94ykk")`, didn't work either.

Comment: *Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.* What do you find in your `soup` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see all my text elements in the object, however fetching them seems like a tough task. I've read through the official docs and some internet tutorials, but they just seem to explain the simple ways to fetch stuff like nested 1 level down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `soup` and comment again, elements are not there, because `requests` do not render elements like a browser would do and so you could not get them the way you tried, but you could grab the information.

Check the `<script>` and their contents, convert it to JSON and than iterate it - Because there is no expected output, this answer is just pointing in a direction.

###### Example

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/new-cryptocurrency-listing?c=48&navId=48'

response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#__APP_DATA').text)['routeProps']['ce50']['catalogs']

for e in data:
    for a in e['articles']:
        a['url']='https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/'+a['code']
        a['catalog']= e['catalogName']
        print(a)
```

###### Output

```
{'id': 152163, 'code': '541daaa5499d4b34a737c97c50c8547e', 'title': 'Binance Adds TRU & More Pairs on Cross Margin', 'type': 1, 'releaseDate': 1678438808772, 'url': 'https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/541daaa5499d4b34a737c97c50c8547e', 'catalog': 'New Cryptocurrency Listing'}
{'id': 152025, 'code': 'dc1fa8e36e8c4cbdb6f200bd3aac916e', 'title': 'Binance Futures Will Launch USDⓈ-M LQTY Perpetual Contract with Up to 20X Leverage', 'type': 1, 'releaseDate': 1678335861744, 'url': 'https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/dc1fa8e36e8c4cbdb6f200bd3aac916e', 'catalog': 'New Cryptocurrency Listing'}
{'id': 151999, 'code': '8ef61bec1227429a910877be141c5af3', 'title': 'Binance Adds CFX/TRY, KEY/USDT, STX/TRY & USTC/USDT Trading Pairs', 'type': 1, 'releaseDate': 1678330804124, 'url': 'https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/8ef61bec1227429a910877be141c5af3', 'catalog': 'New Cryptocurrency Listing'}
{'id': 151651, 'code': '7df3140045c442269e474fce7da493f8', 'title': 'Binance Adds ALCX, DF & More Tokens on Cross Margin and DF on Isolated Margin', 'type': 1, 'releaseDate': 1678162095485, 'url': 'https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/7df3140045c442269e474fce7da493f8', 'catalog': 'New Cryptocurrency Listing'}
{'id': 151620, 'code': '9431a427329d48b2955853366f1e85a4', 'title': 'Binance Options Will List Additional BTCUSDT Monthly Options', 'type': 1, 'releaseDate': 1678155635508, 'url': 'https://www.binance.com/en/support/announcement/9431a427329d48b2955853366f1e85a4', 'catalog': 'New Cryptocurrency Listing'}

...
```

Comment: Thanks @HedgeHog, it works like a charm! This was exactly what I tried to achieve. Good idea to convert that response to a json, if I wouldn't know your solution, my way would have been to use regex. But that would be far away from best practice and a pita.

Viele Grüße aus München nach Bremen :-)

Comment: I'm glad I could help you and give you an idea. For future questions, please always include an expected result and also a few details about the overall picture, that would make it easier to answer the question in a targeted manner. greetings to the south.

Answer (score 0):

It's rendered dynamically by javascript. You won't be able to do this with just bs4.